# Azure Data Factory - Dataset

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Azure Data factory. I am using python for copy activity, but whenever I use Parquet type for data sets it shows an error. Can someone please help me to get rid of this problem?

In json I declared a few properties with type as Parquet

```
"Example": {"type": "Parquet"}
```

Error:

> Subtype value Parquet has no mapping, use base class Dataset.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   msrest.exceptions.ValidationError: Parameter 'Dataset.type' can not 
>   be None.

Answer (score 0):

You may use like below

```
texttype = ParquetFormat()
```